# Yocto glibc-locale do_package installed but not shipped in any package

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am trying to build a custom image on yocto. When I create an image, I get an error in glibc-locale (do_package step).

The error is

```
ERROR: glibc-locale-2.24-r0 do_package: QA Issue: glibc-locale: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
    {
        "a lot of file in /usr/lib/gconv, /usr/share/i18n paths"
    }
    Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
    glibc-locale: 820 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
    ERROR: glibc-locale-2.24-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
    ERROR: glibc-locale-2.24-r0 do_package: Function failed: do_package
    ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/test/rpi/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc-locale/2.24-r0/temp/log.do_package.30243
    ERROR: Task (/home/test/poky-morty/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc-locale_2.24.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

I tried to solve it adding the following in the glibc-locale_2.24.bb file:

> INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "installed-vs-shipped "

When I do this, there is no error in glibc do_package step anymore but I have an error in the do_rootfs step:

```
 ERROR: ekt-image-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Unable to install packages. Command '/home/test/rpi/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/opkg --volatile-cache -f /home/test/rpi/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/ekt-image/1.0-r0/opkg.conf -t /home/test/rpi/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/ekt-image/1.0-r0/temp/ipktemp/ -o /home/test/rpi/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/ekt-image/1.0-r0/rootfs  --force_postinstall --prefer-arch-to-version   install locale-base-en-us' returned 255:
Collected errors:
 * opkg_prepare_url_for_install: Couldn't find anything to satisfy 'locale-base-en-us'.

ERROR: ekt-image-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/test/rpi/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/ekt-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.10085
ERROR: Task (/home/test/rpi/meta-rpi/images/ekt-image.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

I tried to cleanstate glibc, glibc-locale but it does not work.

Edit: I tried to add these lines in my glibc-locale.inc file:

```
FILES_kernel-base += "/usr/share/i18n/charmaps/*"
FILES_kernel-base += "/usr/share/i18n/locales/*"
FILES_kernel-base += "/usr/lib/gconv/*"
FILES_kernel-base += "/usr/share/i18n*"
```

And also these lines:

```
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/share/i18n/charmaps/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/share/i18n/locales/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/lib/gconv/*"
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/share/i18n*"
```

But it does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 7):

I have had this issue, and it seems to be due to leaving out glibc options in the `DISTRO_FEATURES` for the build. If you're redefining `DISTRO_FEATURES`, make sure to include `${DISTRO_FEATURES_LIBC}` in its definition.

See [Re: [yocto] Problem building glibc-locale](https://www.mail-archive.com/yocto@yoctoproject.org/msg33501.html) on the Yocto mailing list.

See also the comments about `DISTRO_FEATURES_LIBC` in [openembedded-core/local.conf.sample.extended at master · openembedded/openembedded-core](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/conf/local.conf.sample.extended).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of adding a distro feature like this:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES += "feature"
```

Try instead:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " feature"
```

The first sentence in my conf/local.conf was overwriting ?= definitions, such as DISTRO_FEATURES_LIBC.